# How to get constructor as MethodInfo using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

The constructor looks like this:

```
public NameAndValue(string name, string value)
```

I need to get it as a MethodInfo using Reflection. It tried the following, but it does not find the constructor (`GetMethod` returns `null`).

```
MethodInfo constructor = typeof(NameAndValue).GetMethod(".ctor", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Type.GetConstructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx). Note this returns a ConstructorInfo rather than a MethodInfo, but they both derive from MethodBase so have mostly the same members.

Answer (score 5):

```
ConstructorInfo constructor = typeof(NameAndValue).GetConstructor
        (new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
```

You should have the elements you need in the ConstructorInfo, I know of no way to get a MethodInfo for a constructor though.

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: I already knew how to get the ConstructorInfo, but I thought I needed MethodInfo, while only MethodBase was required. Thanks for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only thing you were missing was the correct BindingFlags. I don't specify parameter types in this example but you may do so.

```
var typeName = "System.Object"; // for example
var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
var constructorMemberInfos = type.GetMember(".ctor", BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
// Note that constructorMemberInfos will be an array of matches
```